# Как включить автодополнение и подсветку синтаксиса в файле application.properties(IntelliJ IDEA)?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

В некоторых туториалах видел как в файле appliction.properties работает подсветка синтаксиса и автодополнение

[image: подсветка синтаксиса]

У меня же ничего не распознается.

[image: без подсветки]

Использовал и Community, и Ultimate edition.

Comment: Поищите плагин нужный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем то решение, которое хотелось бы, однако нашел плагин
[Spring Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant), который делает автодополнения в .yml файлах, что в принципе то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно установить Properties плагин (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11594-properties)

Comment: Плагины установлены на обоих IDE

Comment: значит, проблема в спринговых плагинах ( раз спринговые проперти не находятся). попробуйте установить все спринговые плагины